How to pass flutter build arguments to snapcraft command when building flutter app using snapcraft
Question
How to pass flutter build arguments to snapcraft command when building flutter app using snapcraft
Expect
When building a flutter app using snapcraft, you can pass flutter build arguments to the snapcraft command
name: app_name
version: 1.0.0
summary: My App description.
description: My App description.
icon: snap/gui/app_name.png
title: AppName
contact: support@mail.com
license: MIT
architectures:
  - build-on: [ amd64 ]
  - build-on: [ arm64 ]

confinement: strict
base: core22
grade: stable

slots:
  dbus-app_name: # adjust accordingly to your app name
    interface: dbus
    bus: session
    name: app.app_name # adjust accordingly to your app name and

apps:
  app_name:
    command: app_name
    extensions: [gnome] # gnome includes the libraries required by flutter
    plugs:
      - network
    slots:
      - dbus-app_name
parts:
  app_name:
    source: .
    plugin: flutter
    flutter-target: lib/main.dart # The main entry-point file of the application


You cannot add params, but can override the build command. Add flutter build linux params like --obfuscate --split-debug-info=build/macos/outputs/symbols
parts:
  app_name:
    source: .
    plugin: flutter
    flutter-target: lib/main.dart
    override-build: |
      rm -rf /root/parts/app_name/build/flutter-distro
      git clone --depth 1 -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git /root/parts/app_name/build/flutter-distro
      flutter precache --linux
      flutter clean
      flutter pub get
      dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
      flutter build linux --release --target lib/main.dart --obfuscate --split-debug-info=build/macos/outputs/symbols
      cp -r build/linux/*/release/bundle/* $CRAFT_PART_INSTALL/

